# getting variables from a downstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a build and deploy process for every artifact. If build or deploy for a single artifact fails it should not stop the whole process.

We have a separate jobs for build and deploy. Build jobs can work in parallel on a slaves, deploy not.

The results of a build job should be used by deploy job. I need somehow to get a workspace location of a build and set it as a parameter of a deploy job. The place where I need to put a workspace is marked with a question mark.

```
def branches = [:]
def artifactsToDeploy = []
node{
    workspace = pwd()
    echo "Workspace:${workspace}"

    //read artifact names from file
    def appFile=readFile(workspace+"@script/artifacts.txt")
    def artifactNames = appFile.tokenize()

    //prepare parallel jobs
    for (int i=0 ; i < artifactNames.size ; i++) {
        def artifactName=artifactNames[i]
        branches[artifactName]={

            //start build job
            def buildResult = build job: 'build-artifact', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARTIFACT', value:artifactName],
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value:SVN_TAG]]

            //need to read workspace from a build job, that was running on a slave
            artifactsToDeploy[artifactsToDeploy.size]=[artifact:artifactName,workspace:?????]
        }
    }

    echo 'pipeline begin'
    stage('build'){
        parallel branches
    }

    stage('deploy'){

        //read artifacts from a list and deploy 
        for (int i=0;i<artifactsToDeploy.size;i++) {
            def buildResult = build job: 'deploy-artifact', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ARTIFACT', value:artifactsToDeploy[i].artifact],
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'WORKSPACE', value:artifactsToDeploy[i].workspace]]
        }
    }
    echo 'pipeline end'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to have the workspace available in the downstream build, just use `archive` to make the artifact persistent and pass the reference in a parameter to the job which needs to know about it, then use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to get the artifact in the downstream job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rawBuild, that can be used. To access a workspace use buildResult.rawBuild.environment.WORKSPACE